# Merging/Concating two observables gives results from only one

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

I have 2 Observables that can execute in parallel. I am trying to merge the 2 observables, but I am getting only the result from one observable back.

```
Observable<AsyncN1qlQueryResult> queryResult = bucket.async().query(n1qlQuery)
    .timeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .retryWhen(anyOf(BackpressureException.class).max(3)
        .delay(Delay.exponential(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 32, 2)).build())
    .retryWhen(anyOf(TemporaryFailureException.class)
        .max(2)
        .delay(Delay.fixed(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)).build())
    .onErrorResumeNext(exp -> {
      return Observable.error(exp);
    });


Observable<Map<String, String>> metricsMap = queryResult.flatMap(qr ->
    qr.info()).map(n1qlMetrics -> {
                resultMap.put("metrics",n1qlMetrics.asJsonObject().toString());
                return resultMap;
                          });

Observable<Map<String, String>> resultObsMap = queryResult.flatMap(asyncN1qlQueryResult ->
    asyncN1qlQueryResult.errors().flatMap(error -> {
      return Observable
          .error(new Exception("unable to execute n1ql query " + error.toString()));
    })
        .switchIfEmpty(asyncN1qlQueryResult.rows())
).map(row -> {
  JsonObject json = ((AsyncN1qlQueryRow) row).value();
  return json.toString();
}).reduce("",(result,next) -> result + (result.equals("") ? "" :
    ",") +  next).map(results -> {resultMap.put("results", results); return resultMap;});
```

when I run the below :

```
Observable<Map<String, String>> retObservable = Observable.concat(resultObsMap, metricsMap);
```

I only get result from resultObsMap back.

Any way I can execute the above two observables resultObsMap and metricsMap in parallel and merge their results together?

Comment: Observable#concat will subscribe to the first observable (resultObsMap) and will emit the values via onNext to subscriber. When the resultObsMap is onComplete,  metricsMap will be subscribed to and will emit it's values via onNext to subscriber. When resultObsMap does emit onComplete, you will not get any values from metricsMap. Please verify that resultObsMap onCompletes. If you want to subscribe to both, please use Observable#combineLatest

Comment: Just use merge operator